# Is it possible to identify a date limit on Python's FTP.retrlines() function?

Tags: python, ftp, python-2.6

I am using the standard Python FTP library to get a file listing and subsequently download files from an FTP site after inspecting the list. This used to be a quick operation, however, the list of files on the site grows daily and is now sufficiently long to cause a significant delay when executing `ftp.retrlines('LIST',readFileCallback)` to get the file listing.

I am not interested in the full listing on the FTP server. Is it possible to e.g. get a listing of files what are only 1 month old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try passing `-t` to `LIST`, some servers support it. This will sort the listing by the modified time (similar to `ls`).

Typically such filtering/sorting is left up to the client to implement. FTP servers are not obligated to provide server-side filtering (beyond basics).